# go language license

Tags: licensing, go

I have asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673778/proper-licensing-for-a-website-built-using-twitter-bootstrap) before but this time I want to focus on `go` language. I have been reading the [wiki page of go language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29) and realized there is a license segment in the summary which says `BSD style + Patent grant`. I'm aware that there is also a `gcc` frontend for `go` which I'm guessing have something like `GPL` license although there was no mention of it in the wiki page, which made me wonder:

**Is the mentioned `BSD` license intended for:**

- the compiler
- and/or the language
- and/or the standard libraries

**if there are such distinctions at all?**

A practical answer would be welcome (i.e. how can I license a source or binary?) as well as a contrast to the old languages (`C`, `C++`, `Java`) if any..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most parts of Go are licensed under a [three-clause BSD style license](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/LICENSE) and [patent grant](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/PATENTS). This includes the gc compilers, standard libraries, and other related tools. There are two notable exceptions I'm aware of:

The [language specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) and other website documentation are licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License. Scroll to the very bottom of any page on golang.org to see. (I suppose this means that some source code comments are licensed the same way, which seems a little strange.)

gccgo's frontend is uses the same BSD style license as the rest of Go, however because it must be linked with the rest of gcc, it's effectively GPLv3. (Note that, contrary to janneb's claims, gccgo does not share any code with the other compiler. It does share some runtime code.)

There are ongoing efforts to separate out the parts of the gccgo frontend that depend on gcc so that it could be used as a frontend for other Go compilers, such as maybe an LLVM-based compiler. Such a compiler could be released completely under the BSD style license.

Comment: Linking with the GNU C run-time is excluded from the GPL licensing requirement to open source your code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838807/license-of-runtime-libraries-included-in-gcc

https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.html

My read of those leads me to believe that you need not open source your Go code simply because you use some C library that brings in the GNU C run-time.

Comment: I'm not claiming that gccgo's frontend is GPL because it links to libc, but because it links to lots of GCC, which does not (as far as I know) have an exclusion. There have been efforts to separate the frontend from GCC, but I believe they're incomplete and currently inactive.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant, @Evan Shaw. This also helped clarify things for me:

"The gccgo compiler is a new frontend for GCC, the widely used GNU compiler. Although the frontend itself is under a BSD-style license, gccgo is normally used as part of GCC and is then covered by the GNU General Public License (the license covers gccgo itself as part of GCC; it does not cover code generated by gccgo"

https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo

Answer (score 0):

The BSD license applies to the compiler and the standard library. I don't know what license the "language itself" is under; what does that even mean, the text of the language spec, or?

The go frontend in GCC is also BSD licensed (AFAIK it shares code with the other go compiler), although the rest of the GCC compiler remains under the GPLv3.